# I am trying to get the Seconds since midnight: 86339

Tags: python

I am trying to get the Seconds since midnight:  86339

I tried writing a program and i get the results

```
Enter hour:11      
Enter minute:58
Enter second:59
Enter frame:PM
Seconds since midnight: 43139
```

```
hour = input("Enter hour:")
minute = input("Enter minute:")
second = input("Enter second:")
frame = raw_input("Enter frame:")

time = ( 3600 * hour + minute * 60 + second )
print "Seconds since midnight:",time
```

This is the actual results i want to produce

```
Enter hour: 11
Enter minute: 58
Enter second: 59
Enter AM or PM: PM
Seconds since midnight:  86339
```

Enter hour: 12 
Enter minute: 7 
Enter second: 20 
Enter AM or PM: AM 
Seconds since midnight: 440

Enter hour: 12 
Enter minute: 14 
Enter second: 57 
Enter AM or PM: PM 
Seconds since midnight: 44097

Comment: Just cause I'm anal: `time = hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + second`

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to use `frame` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

PM needs to add 12 hours

Python 2.X :

```
hour = input("Enter hour:")
minute = input("Enter minute:")
second = input("Enter second:")
frame = input("Enter frame:")

time = ( 3600 * hour +  minute* 60 + second )
if frame == "PM":
    time += 12 * 60 * 60
print "Seconds since midnight:",time
```

Python 3.x:

```
hour = input("Enter hour:")
minute = input("Enter minute:")
second = input("Enter second:")
frame = input("Enter frame:")

time = ( 3600 *int( hour) + int( minute)* 60 + int( second ))
if frame == "PM":
    time += 12 * 60 * 60
print("Seconds since midnight:",time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your time calculation to something like this:

```
time = ( 3600 * hour + minute * 60 + second )
if "PM" == frame:
    time += 12 * 60 * 60
```